# parseInt vs printf %o format modifier

Tags: java

why,

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("17", 8));
```

print out: **15**

and,

```
System.out.printf("%o", 17);
```

print out: **21**

Aren't they supposed to return octal value of 17?

Comment: ty all for your answers

Answer (score 8):

Your first example converts the octal value 17 to decimal, which is 15.

Your second example converts the decimal value 17 to octal, which is 21.

If you modify your second example to use `017` (octal 17), you'll get the same result.

Comment: just an addition, probably OP wanted to use `Integer.toString(17, 8)` in a first part

Comment: I have always wondered why language designers choose the leading zero to represent octal system. It's awfully confusing.

Comment: @uraf It's been that way for ages. For hex you have alternatively 0x20 and 20h, depending on the language. At least with octal they're consistent.

Comment: @Kayaman, I know it was. But why? Guess we will never know. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java API

```
 parseInt(String s, int radix)
```

- s - This is a string representation of decimal.
- radix - This would be used to convert String s into integer.

So your `Integer.parseInt("17", 8)` will convert "17" to decimal using base value of 8 which is resulted 15

`"%o"` is use to format as Octal value so 17 will be represented as a Octal value. And result will be 21

So all the outputs that you get is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%o", 17);
```

This is used to convert an integer into its octal value

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("17", 8));
```

This converts string(ocatal value) to integer.