# Java integer increases unintended

Tags: java, ascii-art

I have a function that takes `String` and a `char[]` type variables as parameter.

```
public String compressLine(String line, char[] fileChars){
  String outputLine = new String();
  int count = 0;
  char lastChar = fileChars[0];
  for(char c : line.toCharArray()){
    if(c!=lastChar){
      outputLine += String.format("%o,", count);
      lastChar = c;
      count = 1;
    }else{
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  outputLine += count;
      return outputLine;
}
```

`String line` is a line of ascii art and the `char[] fileChars` consists of the characters that are used in the string mentioned beforehand.

**Example of `line`:**

> "@@@@@@@@@@---"

**Example of `fileChars`:**

> [-, @]

Algorithm works in the following manner: given a row of data, the algorithm replaces each row with numbers that say how many consecutive pixels are the same character, always starting with the number of occurrences of the character that is encountered first in the `fileChars`.

When I ran a test using the examples given above, It should return;

> `[0, 10, 3]`

But the output I get is;

> `[0, 12, 3]`

When I tried to solve the bug, I saw the integer `count` somehow hops from *7* to *10*.

What is causing this?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `String.format("%o,", count);`, what do you expect this to mean? In particular, what do you expect the `%o` part to mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parseInt vs printf %o format modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530696/parseint-vs-printf-o-format-modifier)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Im new to java and trying to get used to it, so I didn't think I was using the wrong formatting.

Comment: How did you decide to use `%o`, instead of something else? It's a very strange choice to make - if you follow example code, it would be very rare to see it, and tutorials would not talk about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
outputLine += String.format("%o,", count);
```

The `"%o"` output format specifier specifies that the value of `count` should be output in Octal.  When the decimal value of `count` is `10`, the Octal equivalent is `12`.

I expect that you want this instead:

```
outputLine += String.format("%d,", count);
```

PS: When it appears that the number "jumps" from 7 to 10, that's because '10' immediately follows '7' in octal.

Answer (score 4):

`%o` means octal. I'm not sure how you ended up on using `%o`, but, you don't want octal. Octal is how you would count if you have 8 fingers. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.., oh last finger, so.. 10!

In octal, '12' is how you write the tenth number. Just like you'd use '10' to do that in decimal, and '1010' in binary.

You want `%d` for decimal.

Comment: *how you would count if you have 8 fingers*  I have 8 fingers ... and 2 thumbs :-)